# How to accumulate async data?

Tags: algorithm, node.js, design-patterns, asynchronous

I want to summarize data that is produced asynchronously (in node.js). 
How would you do this in a thread safe manner?

For instance,

```
function test(){
  var accumulator = 0;
  for(int i= 0; i<100; i++){
    // non blocking function producing value
    getasyncdata(i, function(value){
      // this is spread over 3 lines to simulate non atomic operation.
      tmp = accumulator;
      tmp = tmp + value;
      accumulator = tmp;
    });
  }
  console.log(accumulator);
}
```

the way I see it getdata callbacks will be called 100 times in parrallel... and there is hight chances accumulator wont be the sum of the 100 values since the callback is not atomic (or is it?)...

What do you think ?

Comment: Node is single-threaded, so your async operations don't actually run at the exact same time.

Comment: On the other hand, `accumulator` would probably be 0 at the time you're console logging it, as the function is async

Comment: Additionally, if you use cluster then the operations could actually run at the same time. See http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function that checks whether any jobs are running, and then prints if we are done. For example:

```
function test(){
  var accumulator = 0, pendingOps = 0;

  for(int i= 0; i<100; i++){
    // non blocking function producing value
    pendingOps++;
    getasyncdata(i, function(value){
      // this is spread over 3 lines to simulate non atomic operation.
      tmp = accumulator;
      tmp = tmp + value;
      accumulator = tmp;
      printIfFinished();
    });

    function printIfFinished() {
      pendingOps--;
      if(pendingOps) == 0 {
        console.log(accumulator);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are a lot of control flow libraries that will help you do this, two of the more popular ones:

- [Batch](https://github.com/visionmedia/batch) (personal favorite)
- [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: How can I be sure, code is actually parallelized, what if getasyncdata  callback is not called faster than next getasyncdata triggered... this would get printIfFinished called before pendingOps gets incremented... no ? imagine getasyncdata doesn't block.

Comment: Batch is great for more complex situation, thanks for the tip. That's what I was looking for.